# Python message.content discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am trying to make my `discord.py`  bot respond automatically when someone sends some word, but the problem is that the command only works if the word is the first thing to be written in the sentence. I want my bot to respond the message even when the word is in the middle of some sentence. If this is possible, how can I do it?

Comment: `message.content.startswith('not')` pretty obviously only looks at the beginning of the string. Either use `if 'not' in message.content` or a regex on the message. As an aside, having a bot triggered every time someone says "not" is going to get really annoying really quickly...

Comment: are you using discord.py or disco?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following example will do what you want.

```
Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="")

@Bot.event

async def on_message(message):

     if "not" in message.content:
           await Bot.send_message(message.channel, 'yes')
```

To clarify, `message.content.startswith` will only check to see if the defined characters/string are at the start of the message, while `message.content` scans the entire message sent.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet should solve the problem.

`main.py`:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message():
    if message.content.startswith(‘Exemple’):
        message.channel.send(‘this is an exemple’)

client.run(os.getenv(‘TOKEN’))
```

`.env`:

```
TOKEN=[paste the bot token here]
```