# How do I accept a string as an argument? (discord.py rewrite)

Tags: python, discord.py, arguments

I am trying to make a discord.py command that accepts a string as a positional argument.

How do I accept a string from a Discord message (and, by extension, booleans and integers) as an argument?

### Example Code

```py
# -- snip --

@bot.command()
async def echo(ctx):
  """
  Example command to return the input of this command.
  """
  # argument name should be called `arg`

  await ctx.respond(arg)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass a positional parameter you can do so like that:

```
async def test(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)
```

The user can then provide an argument when invoking the command:
`$test foo`, which has the output `foo`
when you want to pass an argument with whitespace in between, you can either just quote the argument: `$test "foo bar"`, which has the output `foo bar` or modify your command to handle an undetermined number of parameters:

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, *args)
```

To work with Integers and Boolean values you can make use of some little python tricks to do so. to convert a String that only has Integers in it you can just convert the String to an Integer with `int()` - if the string should be converted to a bool you can work with comparison like:

```
s = "Foo"
#<User puts in a value for s>#
s == "Foo" #Returns a boolean value (True if the string matches, False if it does not)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's literally the first things that appears when reading the introduction to commands, [here's the link](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html?highlight=arguments)

Also here's an example

```py
@bot.command()
async def foo(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)

# To invoke
# !foo hello
# >>> hello
```

Comment: It returns an error. “SyntaxError: invalid syntax.”

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at other questions regarding getting messages from the discord bot?

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/61851683/6595024
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/49127887/6595024

edit: Updated answer given update to question

Comment: Not command line, arguments from command sent in Discord. (Question updated for clarity.)

Comment: Ok, from what I gather is that you want a program that will do something when someone pings it on discord right? I'm assuming something like `@bot play_music Dancing Queen`. Could you elaborate your original question further?

Comment: I have the basic bot, my attempts at pulling a string from the message as a variable failed. I’ll elaborate more

Comment: I saw your update to the question. None of these have an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty Simple
If you want to take an argument without spaces,

```
@bot.command()
async def combinestring(ctx, arg: str):
    #your code
```

If you want to take an argument with spaces,

```
@bot.command()
async def combinestring(ctx, *, arg):
    #your code
```

Done.

Answer (score 0):

A example would be something like a reminder command. For that, you can do the following:

```
@client.command()
async def reminder(ctx, time: int, *, message: str):
```

The time will be a integer, and the message will be a string.